# how to delete card and index of array when a remove button clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I want to delete the whole card and the data in index of array when the remove button clicked.
I show it to you in this photo.

[image]

here is my code :

```js
var list;
function setData() {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var card = document.createElement("li");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var cardBody = document.createElement("div");
    var cardTitle = document.createElement("h4");
    var cardText = document.createElement("p");
    var submit = document.createElement("a");
    var remove = document.createElement("a");

    card.className = "card col-md-3 col-sm-4";
    cardBody.className = "card-body";
    img.className = "card-img-top";
    cardTitle.className = "card-title";
    cardText.className = "card-text";
    submit.className = "btn btn-primary stretched-link";
    remove.className = "btn btn-danger stretched-link";

    img.src = list[i].avatar;

    cardTitle.append(document.createTextNode(list[i].first_name + list[i].last_name));
    cardText.append(document.createTextNode(list[i].email));
    submit.append(document.createTextNode("submit"));
    remove.append(document.createTextNode("remove"));

    cardBody.appendChild(cardTitle);
    cardBody.appendChild(cardText);
    cardBody.appendChild(submit);
    cardBody.appendChild(remove);

    card.appendChild(img);
    card.appendChild(cardBody);
    $("#list").append(card);
  }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
    type: "get",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    success: function (data) {
      list = data.data;
      console.log(list);
      setData();
    },
    error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {
      console.log("error", +status + errorThrown);
    },
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  margin: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>GETTING STARTED WITH BRACKETS</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="row" id="list">
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to remove the index of the date in list when user clicked in the remove button on that index and then call setdate();
thanks a lot I am new in web development.

Comment: You can use splice method to remove item from array based on index. However you need to create a function and call it on remove button click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require a `click` event for your delete button:

```js
remove.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  var btn = ev.target
  var cardBody = btn.parentElement
  var card = cardBody.parentElement

  card.parentElement.removeChild(card)
  setData()
})
```

Or with ES6 arrow functions `() => {}`, which preserves the scope where the function was created in:

```js
remove.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  card // from your creating function

  card.parentElement.removeChild(card)
  setData()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

just before **$("#list").append(card)**  add a click event to the card like this :

```
  card.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{ 
    
      if(event.terget.innerText === 'remove'){    
       card.remove()   
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your list variable is a global variable, If you want to resue the setData function. Please
do it in the below way,
add the remove function for removing data in list.

```
function removeData(index) {
// index starts from 0
let tempList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (i != index)
        tempList.push(list[index]);
}
list = tempList;
setData();}
```

Now,

```
function setData() {
$("#list").empty();
// add eventlistener to remove tag to call the removeDataFunction, rest all code remains the same  
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var card = document.createElement("li");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    remove.addEventListener('click', removeData(i))
    $("#list").append(card);
}}}
```